# Flat Paper Look - How can i make these? And what would I need?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, flat-design, paper

[image: Flat Paper Look]
[image: Flat Paper Look 2]

Is there a name for this style / look? I really like it, but have no idea how to begin or what to look for. What Software would I most likely do this with? Any advice on how one would begin making these?

Answer (score 1):

**Intro:**
well This is the Trend, Google, Microsoft and many other leading tech industries and lead designers are using this Type of Art.
we designer called it as Flat Design, in case of shadow coming in to the existence we called it material design(introduced by google).

**Software and Tools:**
for making these kind of art you can use Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Illustrator, Sketch app or Coreldraw.

When more shapes got more complexity, its hard to create with Photoshop.
yet as i am also a designer i prefer and will suggest you to use Adobe Illustrator.

**Where to Beggin :**

If you are a beginner to the software(Adobe Illustrator) know the Basic things/Tools and be handy with the pen tool, you need it more during creating something.
once you are overcome the basic learning about Adobe illustrator

First start with some basic shape , try to give them some effect. here is an example how you can express a ball in flat format.

[image]
bellow image is also describe about the real vs flat Design 
you can design flat image inspired from the flat image like this

[image]

Not only by making perfect shape your design will see perfect, for it main thing is color, to choosing color is very difficult things for designer,for making 2D type,  shadow type art you need relative colors to the main colors.
you can check it by googling google Material UI colors

there are some site like materialup , you will get inspired from this site.
you can take some tutorial in youtube too may be help full to you for making further design.
once you expert on these thing you can create Character/ Avatar Easily l

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. however, i feel like the examples you posted are not really quite what I am looking for. The images I posted look much more realistic and paperlike, not just like the classic flat design. Do you not think so? or might i be missing something crucial here?

Comment: in the Photo you added there is shadow effect is there. yes i agreed that i talked more about the flat. but the process is like this what i said. i think you have to definitely try this one :)

Answer (score 0):

The style looks like paper folded in an origami style. Here's a tutorial which covers a similar effect:
[Origami effect in Photoshop](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-japanese-origami-using-one-dollar-bills-in-adobe-photoshop--cms-27033)